# CSS scrolling text - remove delay and format div height or text padding

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have added some custom CSS for scrolling text to my site (built in SquareSpace), but am struggling to amend the code to

**1.**  add some padding around the text so the text is central with some space around it - I've tried several ways but none seem to work.

**2**. remove the delay between the next round of scrolling starts.  I have tried changing to -100%, 0 based on an answer in another thread here, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.scroll{
   color:#ce0058; 
   height:100px; 
   padding-bottom:20px; 
   font-size:30px; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   overflow: hidden!important; 
   white-space: nowrap; 
   position: absolute!important;
   -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
   -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
   transform:translateX(100%);
   -moz-animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
   animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
  }
  
 @-moz-keyframes scroll {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll  {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }

#page {
   overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

Page link: https://www.interaction-ld.com/coaching_new

```html
<div id="content" class="main-content" data-content-field="main-content" data-collection-id="604791783e6fec3843566230" data-edit-main-image="">
  <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-type="page" data-updated-on="1616415825860" id="page-604791783e6fec3843566230">
    <div class="row sqs-row">
      <div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">
        <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-802d3782e68922228fe2">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <h1 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Coaching</h1>
            <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">We recognise the power of coaching to harness potential and how this is an essential skill in todays organisations.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1615303065411_14017">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <div class="scroll">Change management – performance development – leadership development – executive development - career development – personal confidence – personal brand - relationship management – influence - transition needs – team dynamics – high performance
              teams – dysfunctional teams – culture change – wellbeing - resilience</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1615304108607_7019">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Our team of diverse, qualified, highly experienced coaches work at all levels of an organisation from graduate’s to Executives to help people perform to their peak. Whether that’s 1:1 coaching or group coaching we can meet your needs.</p>
            <p
              class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">The coaching we deliver has been called <strong>transformational </strong>and this last year has demonstrated how critical this type of intervention is to support people’s personal development in challenging and ever-changing circumstances.</p>
              <p
                class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Demand has never been higher.</p>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;"><strong>How can we help?</strong></p>
                <h2 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">How we will work with you</h2>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">We will work in close partnership with you to understand your need and which approach/s is best.</p>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">We will follow our renowned 4 C’s process to ensure consistently high standards, wrap around support and optimum results, both for the individual, group and the organisation.</p>
                <h2 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Our coaching team</h2>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">We have been delivering one to one, group coaching and coaching programmes for over 20 years using our diverse team of professionally qualified and accredited coaches. </p>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">With extensive industry and sector experience our coaches understand the challenges and pressures faced by those in different roles and levels within an organisation.</p>
                <p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">We are a Member of the <a href="https://www.associationforcoaching.com/members/public_profile.asp?id=60751214" target="_blank">Association for Coaching</a> International professional body and follow and implement their ‘Global Code of
                  Ethics’. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block horizontalrule-block sqs-block-horizontalrule" data-block-type="47" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1615304108607_24639">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block horizontalrule-block sqs-block-horizontalrule" data-block-type="47" id="block-58fe2f2a68bf7a643a7d">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LKelly at least add your html to create a [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here is the page: https://www.interaction-ld.com/coaching_new

Comment: @LKelly add your HTML HERE, don't post a link as links become invalid and the question will become useless to future users if that happens.

Comment: Oh, sorry - someone asked for a link, so that's why I sent one

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to your problem, try this

```
 `#page {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }`
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do already have that in the css and all it does it keep the text within the page width rather than any padding or delay setting.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the scrolling delay - I can control how quickly it appears again, but editing the percentage in the webkit-keyframes - I have gone for 25% as 0% made it appear suddenly rather than scroll across.

```
@-moz-keyframes scroll {
0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(0, 0); }
100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%, 0); }

}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll  {
0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(25%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
```